# Windows 10 MessageWebsocket adding cookie

Tags: c#, websocket, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I'm writing a Windows 10 app in which I'm trying to connect a websocket to the IRCCloud api.

The IRCCloud api requires the following request headers:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: WebSocket
Connection: Upgrade
User-Agent: [REDACTED]
Cookie: session=[REDACTED]
Sec-WebSocket-Key: [REDACTED]==
Host: api.irccloud.com
Origin: https://api.irccloud.com
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
```

I'm using the following code to connect the websocket to the api:

```
MessageWebSocket Socket = new MessageWebSocket();
Socket.SetRequestHeader("Origin", "https://api.irccloud.com");
Socket.SetRequestHeader("Cookie", "session=" + info.Session);    
Socket.MessageReceived += Socket_MessageReceived;
await Socket.ConnectAsync(new Uri("wss://" + Host + Path));
```

However, when I connect I get an authentication error due to the Websocket adding a cookie all by itself with the name __cfduid. IRCClouds API is very specific in that the session cookie should be the ONLY cookie that's in the request header. The session key is retrieved with a Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient.

I verified all my other parameters with the IRCCloud devs, who are saying they are correct, and they also pointed me to the cookie. So my question is, how do I remove the cookie? There's no public method for it in the MessageWebSocket class that seems to work for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WebSockets API uses the same underlying stack as `Windows.Web.Http` namespace, so, you will need to remove the cookies manually using something like this:

```
var filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
var cookieManager = filter.CookieManager;

var uri = new Uri("http://example.com/foo/bar");
foreach (var cookie in cookieManager.GetCookies(uri))
{
    cookieManager.DeleteCookie(cookie);
}
```